# Do variables reset to their initial values after every post method in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

```
//jshint esversion:6

var logger;
var logName;
var pollName;
var names = [];

const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const readline = require('readline');
const fileName1 = __dirname + "/public/logger.json";
const fileName2 = __dirname + "/public/poll.json";
const dataWriter1 = require(fileName1);
const dataWriter2 = require(fileName2);
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
var reader = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/public/names.txt'),
  console: false
});

reader.on('line', function(line) {
  names.push(line);
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.get("/route", function(req, res)
{
  fs.readFile(fileName1,'utf-8',(err,data)=>
{
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(data);
});
});

app.post("/", function(req, res)
{

  if(req.body.button==1)
  {
    logName = req.body.name;
    console.log(logName);
    for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
    {
      if (logName == names[i])
      {
        logger=true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(logger!=true)
    {
      logger=false;
    }
    dataWriter1.logger = logger;
    fs.writeFile(fileName1, JSON.stringify(dataWriter1), function writeJSON(err)
    {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(dataWriter1));
    });
    logger=false;
  }

  else if(req.body.button==2)
  {
    console.log(logName);
    pollName=req.body.option;
    for(i=0;i<dataWriter2.list.length;i++)
    {
      if(dataWriter2.list[i].name==pollName)
      {
        dataWriter2.list[i].votes++;
        dataWriter2.list[i].voter_name.push(logName); 
        //logName is undefined
      }
    }
    fs.writeFile(fileName2, JSON.stringify(dataWriter2), function writeJSON(err)
    {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(dataWriter2));
    });
  }

  res.redirect("/");
});


app.listen(3000, function()
{
  console.log("Server Started!");
});
```

This is my server code in node.js. I have 2 forms in `index.html` and both have submit buttons with different `value` to differentiate. The first form has to be submitted to view the second form. My problem is that even though I'm storing a data from the first form in a variable it resets when I submit the second form even though when the server is still running.
I cannot understand why `logName` becomes undefined while I'm posting with the second submit button and is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.. The server was restarting due to changes in a JSON file as I was running it by nodemon. Added JSON file to ignore list and now it's all fine.